# Input Stream Returning null when using classLoader

Tags: android, classloader, inputstream

I have some files in the sdcard in this location:

```
/Android/data/com.abc.xyz/files/main.1.com.abc.xyz.obb/myfile.xml
```

I am trying to read the file from the above path and return an input stream, but the input stram is returning is null, i have checked the path also it is correct.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if (classLoader == null) {
        classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    }
// here filepath is the path that i have added above.
    inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filePath);
    return inputStream;
    }
```

Why i am getting null?